# RabbitMQ Not listening on my wlan0 IP address

Tags: java, android, tcp, rabbitmq

Can't connect/send data from a java app to RabbitMQ server IP 192.168.1.8 on another computer. Running the java app on server with IP 127.0.0.1 works fine.

`$ netstat -tulpn | grep 56`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16457/beam.smp  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16457/beam.smp  
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      16457/beam.smp
```

How do I make it listen to 192.168.1.0/32 ?

Comment: can you check the logs? are you using user name `guest` and passowrd `guest` to login ?

Comment: The logs resolved my issue, now I have created a different user.

=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Jan-2017::23:01:47 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1237.0> (192.168.43.1:33942 -> 192.168.43.8:5672):
{handshake_error,starting,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' can only connect via localhost",
                             'connection.start_ok'}}